# Using Leaflet with plugin in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, leaflet

I'm building an app with Meteor 1.3, and I need Leaflet and [leaflet-measure](https://github.com/ljagis/leaflet-measure). I've installed both with NPM, and import them to my file with `import`. I have a simple template with a map-`div`, and a corresponding JS-file with a `onRendered`-callback. It creates my Leaflet-map and it works.

The problem starts when trying to add Leaflet-measure:

- Using NPM and importing tells me that a method in `fs` is missing, but installing and importing that as well does not help.
- I've tried adding the `dist`-files to a `lib`-folder in `client` and importing them, but I get an error that indicates that the code hasn't been run:

[image: Error message from leaflet-measure]

How can I make a plugin like this work with Meteor?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ninjaPixel No, no solution to be seen. Ended up moving away from Meteor and writing it in something else.